# Required a selection within SPAN tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form where the user needs to select a rating by choosing the amount of stars.

The stars is within a form where the stars is implemented with a span tag and ahref - each star has an ahref-tag.

```
<form novalidate="" class="comment-form" id="commentform" method="post" action="http://example.com/example.php">
    <p class="star-rating-wrapper">
        <span class="star-rating-label">Din anmeldelse</span>
        <span class="star-rating-stars">
            <a data-rating="5" href="" class="star-rating"></a>
            <a data-rating="4" href="" class="star-rating"></a>
            <a data-rating="3" href="" class="star-rating"></a>
            <a data-rating="2" href="" class="star-rating"></a>
            <a data-rating="1" href="" class="star-rating"></a>
        </span>
    </p>
</form>
```

The question is how do I make it required to have selected one of the stars when it's not an input field ?

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript that implements the star rating you need to also set something like a hidden input that can then be validated against.

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable (validateStar) to false for boolean validation.  Add onClick="starClick()" to each of your star buttons inside the span, and create a function for starClick() to set the value of validateStar to true.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var validateStar = false;

function starClick() {
    var validateStar = true; 
} 
</script>

<span class="star-rating-stars">
    <a data-rating="5" href="" class="star-rating" onClick="starClick()"></a>
    <a data-rating="4" href="" class="star-rating" onClick="starClick()"></a>
    <a data-rating="3" href="" class="star-rating" onClick="starClick()"></a>
    <a data-rating="2" href="" class="star-rating" onClick="starClick()"></a>
    <a data-rating="1" href="" class="star-rating" onClick="starClick()"></a>
</span>
```

Once you've done this just create a validation check that checks if validateStar is true or false.

Comment: How do I do this validation check - again with javascript ? And then if false , how do I avoid that the form is submitted anyway ?

Comment: Yes, you do the validation again with javascript and instead of using an <input type="submit">  use <button onClick=""> When the button is clicked have it execute the validation. If the validation is passed submit the form, if it's failed output an error asking the user to select a star rating.